# Clusters: how to improve results for text classification

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, pca, text-classification

I am trying to classify texts using kmeans, TfidfVectorizer, PCA. However, it seems that many texts are not correctly classified as you can see: I have texts in cluster2 that should be in Cluster 0 or 1. 
My question is on how to improve the results, if increasing the number of clusters or adding more constraints (like specific words to look at for clustering texts).

Help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[image: 1]

Code:

```
def preprocessing(line):
    line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", line.lower())
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_lemmed = [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w) for w in words if w not in stop_words]
    return words_lemmed


vect =TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=preprocessing)
vectorized_text=vect.fit_transform(df['Text'])
kmeans =KMeans(n_clusters=n).fit(vectorized_text)


cl=kmeans.predict(vectorized_text)
df['Predicted']=pd.Series(cl, index=df.index)

df.groupby("Predicted").count()

kmeans_labels =KMeans(n_clusters=n).fit(vectorized_text).labels_

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())])
X = pipeline.fit_transform(df['Text']).todense()
pca = PCA(n_components=n).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)


kmeans.fit(X)
centers2D = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
labels=kmeans.labels_
cluster_name = ["Cluster"+str(i) for i in set(labels)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged this as text-classification, but describe your efforts to cluster the documents. My answer is based on the assumption that you don't know how the documents are grouped for you to classify new documents. The first step would be to determine the clusters/classes/groups and then classify new documents.

There are at least 2 things one can think of for this problem.

1. Clustering Algorithm
2. Data for the clustering algorithm

#### 1. Clustering Algorithm

K-Means clustering is a simple and fast algorithm that produces adequate results. It is almost always the first tool that people reach for, but it has some limitations
a) User must choose the number of clusters ahead of running it
b) Data must not be very sparse
c) Data must be reasonably distributed around the centroid - spherical in nature

See also, [k-Means Advantages and Disadvantages](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/algorithm/advantages-disadvantages).

Do you know apriori, how many clusters you have? You could experiment by running the algorithm multiple times with different cluster sizes and observing the silhouette score. Then choose the one with the best score or one that fits your expectations the best.

There are other algorithms that might suit your needs better, like **DBSCAN** or **Agglomerative clustering**. They don't require the user to choose number of parameters, but do require you to pass in metrics to determine cluster separation. I've used DBSCAN effectively, but don't have as much experience with Agglomerative clustering. Once again, you may have to experiment with the _min_samples_ and *eps* parameters for DBSCAN. SKlearn has good description in the [Clustering User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

#### 2. Data for clustering algorithm

TF-IDF is a good metric for the text and it is a simple and quick way to produce. It is a representation of the different terms that occur with the documents and the weight associated with it. You have a few different options to try out

1. [sklearn.TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) can take a **custom vocabulary**. This will help by reducing the vocabulary to important terms. Also, as suggested by @Graph4Me, you should eliminate stopwords. Both of these techniques will reduce the sparsity of the matrix, in turn making your clustering algorithms more efficient.
2. Change from a TF-IDF model to use an **[word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding)**. This is much more complex, but you could use [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) or [BERT](https://www.blog.google/products/search/search-language-understanding-bert/) to produce them. Spacy can also produce an embedding vector.This will give you an contextual representation rather than just a count/density based on presence of words.

Answer (score 1):

It can be improved in many ways. However, the best start would be if you elaborate on your pipeline together with choosen parameters, as well as your data.

Comment: Thank you Graph4Me. Could you please give me some tips (or just an example) on that (on parameters to choose) and what you mean with elaborate my data? The only thing that I have done was to remove stopwords from texts. Many thanks

Comment: Among other things, the following details are missing: Do you apply Kmeans on TfidfVectorizer or do you apply TfidfVectorizer, then PCA, then K-means ? What is your selected K. How exactly do you use TfidfVectorizer? What are you vectors? In which way should the text in the clusters be similar?

Comment: Also note, of course you can apply word2vec other more modern techniques, but if you really want to learn something, I would not recommend just plug-in some tools at the beginning but to understand why the current method fails..

Comment: Do you have labels? A training set of documents where you know how they should be clustered?

Comment: I updated the question including code. @Graph4Me

Comment: Thanks for the update. There are still some questions left. 1) Why do you have 3 clusters, if number of clusters equals number of dimensions in PCA, but you show a 2D plot ? 2) why do you call kmeans fit several times? Why do you couple dimension of PCA with clusters of kmeans? Do you have groundtruth?

Comment: the number of clusters was manually selected. I did not know how to set the number of dimension in PCA. I coupled dimension of PCA with clusters of kmeans as somewhere in the community or on google II found a similar code, but maybe this can explain why I am making mistakes. Could you please give me some tips soon how it should be look like to be correct (in somehow)?

Comment: As mentioned by @Anandologist, kmeans does not work well in high dimensions. Thus you should try to apply PCA before Kmeans.

Comment: Applying PCA after Kmeans and projecting could merge different clusters,  which is not what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108994/discussion-between-graph4me-and-luca-di-mauro).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the concatenated vector of average word2vec and max pool word2vec. You may get better results than tfidf and PCA. Remove the words like stop words. Also, try with lemmatized words.
If you okay with computational time, go for transformer-based transfer learning embedding like BERT, ALBERT etc...

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches can be applied. In addition to the other answers, you can check: http://brandonrose.org/clustering#Tf-idf-and-document-similarity